# C# match IIS and Oracle Server log loops

Tags: c#, oracle, iis

I have a somewhat difficult question for someone who is learning c# for about the last 6 weeks.

I have two comma delimited files that I stream into an array. The first has a column d:m:y h:m:s. I need to match it with a second text file, comma delimited, I need to match the d:m:y h:m:s in the second file to the first file. only problem is, the seconds must match to the same second or second + 1, and I need to print the line to a third file.

For example I could have:

```
File 1           File 2
d:m:y h:m:s      d:m:y h:m:s,UUID - 1
d:m:y h:m:s      d:m:y h:m:s+1,UUID - 2
d:m:y h:m:s      d:m:y h:m:s+1,UUID - 3
```

Also the UUID must be unique in 1:1 relationship.
File 1 is an IIS server log.
File 2 is an Oracle server log.

The end goal is to match time difference between the to server logs to find out which processes are taking too long.

Does this make sense? Code is below.

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // open server file
    StreamReader readServerFile = new StreamReader(strServerFile);
    readServerFile.ReadLine();

    // open message file
    StreamReader readMessageLog = new StreamReader(strMessageLog);
    readMessageLog.ReadLine();

    // write line to file - false does not append
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strSavedLog, true);
    string strHeader = "Ast Timestamp,Method,Service,IP Address,Time Taken, Time Taken(s),Log Filename,UUID,Request Created,Request Type,Response Created,Result Description,Sender,Time Span,Resp-Req(s)";
    writer.WriteLine(strHeader);

    // loop through server file and copy to save log
    foreach (string strServerLine in File.ReadLines(strServerFile))
    {
        string[] ServerLogWord = strServerLine.Split(',');

        if (ServerLogWord[0] != "Ast Timestamp")
        {
            // extract - server log "Ast Timestamp" convert to date
            string strServerLogAstTimestamp = ServerLogWord[0];
            string AstServerLogTimestamp = strServerLogAstTimestamp.ToString();

            DateTime ServerFileLogDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AstServerLogTimestamp, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);

            // convert time taken in MS to Sec
            int timeTaken = Convert.ToInt32(ServerLogWord[4]);
            int timeTakenSeconds = timeTaken / 1000;

            // loop through message file
            foreach (string strMessageLine in File.ReadLines(strMessageLog))
            {
                string[] MessageLogWord = strMessageLine.Split(',');

                if (MessageLogWord[0] != "ID")
                {
                    // extract - message log - "requestcreated" convert to date
                    string strMessageLogRequestCreated = MessageLogWord[2];
                    string AstMessageLogRequestCreated = strMessageLogRequestCreated.ToString();
                    DateTime MessageLogDateTimeRequestCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(AstMessageLogRequestCreated);

                    // extract - message log - "responsecreated" convert to date
                    string strMessageLogResponseCreated = MessageLogWord[5];
                    string AstMessageLogResponseCreated = strMessageLogResponseCreated.ToString();
                    DateTime MessageLogDateTimeResponseCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(AstMessageLogResponseCreated);

                    // time calculations
                    // calculate timespan
                    TimeSpan ts = MessageLogDateTimeResponseCreated.Subtract(ServerFileLogDateTime);
                    // ***** Change x to modify the time range, must add + or -:  -----  'AddSeconds(x)'
                    DateTime desiredTime = ServerFileLogDateTime.AddSeconds(1);

                    // calculate the time  
                    TimeSpan respReqTimeTaken = MessageLogDateTimeResponseCreated.Subtract(MessageLogDateTimeRequestCreated);

                    // if timestamps match
                    if (MessageLogDateTimeResponseCreated == ServerFileLogDateTime && MessageLogDateTimeRequestCreated <= desiredTime)
                    {
                       if (ServerFileLogDateTime)
                       {
                          string SavedLog = string.Join(",", AstServerLogTimestamp, ServerLogWord[1], ServerLogWord[2], ServerLogWord[3], ServerLogWord[4], timeTakenSeconds, ServerLogWord[5], MessageLogWord[1], AstMessageLogRequestCreated, MessageLogWord[3], AstMessageLogResponseCreated, MessageLogWord[7], MessageLogWord[9], ts, respReqTimeTaken);
                          // write line to save log
                          writer.WriteLine(SavedLog);
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a column in IIS log called "time-taken", it is defined as "The length of time that the action took, in milliseconds.". By checking the value of this column you know how long each request takes.

Please check this link [W3C Extended Log File Format (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true)

Also try LogParser, it's a great tool to examine IIS logs.

Your solution is creative but I don't think it is the ideal approach.

Comment: Your purpose is "to find out which processes are taking too long". Just by checking IIS log you can find "which request takes most time to run". Matching the time stamp between IIS and Oracle log is not recommended.

Comment: Hi Eric I appreciate the help.  I am trying to get to the bottom of some webservices going off the screen for clients, or completely crashing. What I am hoping to accomplish is to find out which processes are crashing/hanging the system. Its an ASP website that communicates with IIS, Oracle and ArcSDE.  Hence trying to compare server logs.

Comment: What I'm thinking is your ASP site must be hosted in a web server, usually IIS. You can check the IIS log first to find out which request takes the longest time to run or return error code. Then examine what's happening in the request.

Comment: Thanks Eric I appreciate you taking the time to help a fella out.

Comment: The boss still wanted the code written so I essentially made two lists and used timespan to match between -1, 0 and 0 seconds, reading one file and then the next on a 1 to 1 basis. I then wrote the server files that don't match to a rogue server file.  What I found was that there would be the odd line in the server file that didn't match with the next line, when I removed the server file line that didn't match and looped through the lines again and they would match.  Just got word from the boss.. Project done.. sweet.